# How to declare an array of objects with initial value in PHP?

Tags: php

Is there a way to declare an initialized array of objects? Something like this (close to the Typescript way):

```
class MyClass {
}

class MySecondClass
{
    public $myArray = [new MyClass(), new MyClass()];
}
```

Comment: Your code is valid in except of "public" that should be removed

Comment: Sure there is, just do what you suggest.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I'm trying to achieve it inside a class. There is no problem outside.

Comment: yeah. You cannot. Do it in a constructor.

Comment: To put more context to the (correct) comment posted by @UnamataSanatarai: [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php): _This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization **must be a constant value**--that is, **it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information** in order to be evaluated._

Comment: @AlonEitan, Thanks. So, how object initialization look like? Can object be a constant like in JavaScript?